# Edge timestamp in gremlin

Tags: java, titan, gremlin

Can I get time-stamp of `edge & vertex` created in gremlin

```
a.addEdge("has",b)
```

`a & b` are two vertices. How do I get the time of edge creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edges (or rather elements in general) do not have any metadata if that's what you're asking for. You'll have to store the timestamp of creation as a property when you create the edge. Later you can query the timestamp just like any other property.

```
// create the edge
a.addEdge("has", b, "created", System.currentTimeMillis())

// get the timestamp
g.V(a).outE("has").filter(inV().is(b)).values("created")
```